# What approach could I use to unit test the output of SAAJ SOAPMessage?

Tags: unit-testing, soap, saaj

I'm using SAAJ to create SOAP envelops that contain XML content in the body and a group of attachments as HTTP `multipart/mixed` content, I need to create a unit test for the method that creates SOAPMessage and the final output of SoapConnection.call().

My current approach is to compare the result of soapMessage.write() (this method outputs the attachment and the soapEnvelope as HTTP request) with the actual expected result but im having all kind of troubles to parse the HTTP request and in comparing the resulting SOAP messages, any suggestions?